# Overpass XML query for finding all buildings inside a polygon

Tags: openstreetmap, java, overpass-api

I want to run following Overpass QL query in order to get way IDs of all buildings inside a polyon:

```
way(poly:"50.7 7.1 50.7 7.2 50.75 7.15")[building];
>;
out ids;
```

Since I'm using the [osm-common](https://github.com/kodapan/osm-common) library, I need to convert this script to Overpass XML. I did it using the convert form [here](http://overpass-api.de/query_form.html).

The result:

```
<osm-script>
    <query into="_" type="way">
        <polygon-query bounds="50.7 7.1 50.7 7.2 50.75 7.15" into="_"/>
        <has-kv k="building" modv="" v=""/>
    </query>
    <recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
    <print from="_" limit="" mode="ids_only" order="id"/>
</osm-script>
```

But when I run it, I get node IDs, not way IDs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note>
<meta osm_base="2013-11-06T07:51:02Z"/>

  <node id="252553109"/>
  <node id="252553111"/>
  <node id="252553112"/>
  <node id="252553114"/>
  <node id="252553115"/>
  <node id="252553117"/>
  <node id="255302992"/>
  <node id="255302993"/>
  <node id="255302995"/>
  <node id="255763355"/>
  <node id="255763356"/>
  <node id="255763357"/>
  <node id="255763358"/>
  <node id="255763430"/>
  <node id="255763431"/>
  <node id="255763432"/>
...
  <node id="2519505892"/>
  <node id="2519505893"/>
  <node id="2519505894"/>
  <node id="2519505895"/>
  <node id="2519505896"/>

</osm>
```

How should I modify the Overpass XML query in order to get way IDs of the buildings?

Answer (score 4):

When I manually enter a Query for ways Overpass turbo suggests an auto repair so as to also get nodes for the way. This then amounts to

```
way(poly:"50.7 7.1 50.7 7.2 50.75 7.15")["building"];
/*added by auto repair*/
(._;>;);
/*end of auto repair*/
out body;
```

see http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1q1 .

Change `out body` to `out ids` if you really only want way IDs, but without the information which node belongs to which way.

Answer (score 2):

if you only need the ids you should remove the line

```
<recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
```

this line is converting your ways to nodes.

Note: you will only get id of the way, but not the geometry because co-ordinates are stored in nodes. If you need both you will have to union the way and nodes

```
<osm-script>
    <query into="_" type="way">
        <polygon-query bounds="50.7 7.1 50.7 7.2 50.75 7.15" into="_"/>
        <has-kv k="building" modv="" v=""/>
    </query>
    <!-- added by auto repair -->
    <union into="_">
      <item set="_"/>
      <recurse from="_" type="down"/>
    </union>
    <!-- end of auto repair -->
    <print from="_" limit="" mode="body" order="id"/>
</osm-script>
```